# SRS how enable HTTPS for HLS stream?

Tags: http-live-streaming, simple-realtime-server

I use Ubuntu 16 server with apache and let's encrypt certificates. I have compiled SRS today directly from Git, so I have the latest version. I'm trying to enable HTTPS on all site, I have a player which load HSL stream passed by RTMP. How can I enable SSL? Now I receive the connection closed error. I've tried to move the path of HLS stream to one folder covered by certificate with no results.

This is the link for SRS: https://github.com/ossrs/srs

If someone needs more detail I can reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NGINX or CaddyServer, you could set HTTPS proxy for SRS, please read [#2881](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/2881), it works like this:

```
OBS --> SRS --HTTP--> NGINX --HTTPS--> Viewers
```

> Note: It's a HTTPS reverse proxy, if you need a HLS cluster, please read [this](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/wiki/v4_EN_SampleHlsCluster).

However, `ossrs/srs` has support for https but they don't enable it by default. So do this to enable https

1. I install `ossrs/srs` by using docker, default config uses port 8088 for https so remember to expose that port for docker

   ```
    docker run -d -p 1935:1935 -p 1985:1985 -p 8080:8080 -p 8088:8088 \
        ossrs/srs:v4 ./objs/srs -c conf/srs.conf
   ```
2. Change `http_server` part in config file '/usr/local/srs/conf/srs.conf'

   Change from

   ```
    http_server {
        enabled         on;
        listen          8080;
        dir             ./objs/nginx/html;
    }
   ```

   To

   ```
    http_server {
        enabled         on;
        listen          8080;
        dir             ./objs/nginx/html;
        https {
            # Whether enable HTTPS Streaming.
            # default: off
            enabled on;
            # The listen endpoint for HTTPS Streaming.
            # default: 8088
            listen 8088;
            # The SSL private key file, generated by:
            #       openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
            # default: ./conf/server.key
            key ./conf/server.key;
            # The SSL public cert file, generated by:
            #       openssl req -new -x509 -key server.key -out server.crt -days 3650 -subj "/C=CN/ST=Beijing/L=Beijing/O=Me/OU=Me/CN=ossrs.net"
            # default: ./conf/server.crt
            cert ./conf/server.crt;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Remember to upload your `server.key` and `server.crt` to `conf` folder (you can generated self signed certificate by comment guidelines above)
4. Restart docker to complete